# Error installing .NET Framework 3.5 on Windows 10

Tags: installation, windows-10, .net-framework

Since I upgraded to Windows 10 I'm no longer a "real" administrator on my personal computer and I can't download anything from Windows Update.

When I try to install .NET 3.5 I get

> Error 0x800F081F

I already tried to change the source directly in the command panel (as admin) but it gave me a error message that the source was not found with the same error code.

Comment: As per http://windows.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows-8/windows-update-error-0x800f081f that means that part of Windows Update files are damaged/missing. Have you tried `dism.exe /online /cleanup-image /scanhealth` and `dism.exe /online /cleanup-image /restorehealth` as per the same page? I don't think that the error code changed in Win10.

Comment: @Evengard - It didn't change but the author, because he isn't an Administrator, cannot use those commands.  Of course that isn't your fault, because the solution of course, should be solved by the Administrator and not the author.

Comment: I understood like "he is the administrator but because of some problems with the system (like damaged files) he was locked out of the Windows Update". But well whatever, that problem can't be solved by a user with a limited account.

Comment: @Evengard - I have tried, in the command panel, the two lines you gaves me, but after finish analysing the seconde one, it gave me the message 0x800f0906, Impossible to download the sources files

Answer (score 9):

Take a look at [.NET Framework 3.5-Installationsfehler: 0x800F0906, 0x800F081F, 0x800F0907](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2734782) :

I prefer the method 3: Use Windows installation media.

You can use the Windows installation media as the file source when you enable the .NET Framework 3.5 feature. To do this, follow these steps:

- Insert the Windows installation media.
- At an elevated command prompt, run the following command:

> Dism /online /enable-feature /featurename:NetFx3 /All
>   /Source:`<drive>:`\sources\sxs /LimitAccess

- Note In this command,  is a placeholder for the drive letter for the DVD drive or for the Windows installation media. For example, you run the following command:

> Dism /online /enable-feature /featurename:NetFx3 /All
>   /Source:D:\sources\sxs /LimitAccess

Comment: I already tried that, but it gave me the message that a can't operate this operation because it don't find the media (is a USB key is a good media ?)

Comment: @David - You tell us?  You really need to allow somebody who understands what they are doing solve this problem.  You cannot fix this as a normal unprivileged user anyways.

Comment: @David I found a guide on how to change your password at [how to geek](http://www.howtogeek.com/222262/how-to-reset-your-forgotten-password-in-windows-10/). When you get the command prompt, instead of creating a new account and adding it to administrators, add your account, and I think after the command prompt step, you need to restore utilman.exe by executing `del c:\windows\system32\utilman.exe` and `move c:\windows\system32\utilman.exe.bak c:\windows\system32\utilman.exe`. replace c with where your your window installation is both where replacing and restoring utilman.exe.

Comment: I did it off a USB, no hiccups(it probably faster than a cd as it is USB 2.0).

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the Windows on Demand ISO (`en_windows_10_features_on_demand_x64_dvd_6846440.iso`, `en_windows_10_features_on_demand_x86_dvd_6848469.iso`) from MSDN subscription , mount the ISO and run those commands:

```
DISM.EXE /Online /Add-Capability /CapabilityName:NetFx3~~~~ /Source:DVD_DRIVE_Letter:\

DISM.EXE /Online /Add-Package /PackagePath:DVD_DRIVE_Letter:\Microsoft-Windows-NetFx3-OnDemand-Package.cab
```

Does this work?

Answer (score 0):

GOTO below link and download cab installer as per your windows version and grab cab file from Windows 10 Installation media sources\sxs\xxxxxxxxx.cab and install using below utility. It is very simple and best way to install .net 3.5 offline for windows 10
http://www.tenforums.com/windows-updates-activation/16712-windows-10-update-cab-file-installer.html

Comment: Download link on forum is dead